# Any simple way in bash to handle escaped UTF8 int?

Tags: bash, shell, unicode, escaping, printf

we have an internal utility with output like this:

```
$ ./my_cmd 
"abc\228\184\173\230\150\135ABC"
```

The escaped int (not oct) are from utf8 stream bytes, separated by slash, we can escape it using python

```
>>> ''.join(chr(int(c)) for  c in  r"\228\184\173\230\150\135".split('\\') if c).decode('utf8')
u'\u4e2d\u6587'
>>> print u'\u4e2d\u6587'
中文
```

My question is are there any convenient shell utilities which could escape it instead of python?

It will act like this

```
$ ./my_cmd 
"abc\228\184\173\230\150\135ABC"
$ ./my_cmd  | some_utility
abc中文ABC
```

I tried to study bash's `printf` and the `/usr/bin/printf` these seems can't handle it. Can can one come up with a cool and easy to remember `perl` or `sed/awk` hack?

Comment: The output format is kind of wacky; many tools would expect the backslash to introduce an *octal* character code.

Comment: @tripleee unfortunately this is already the case. Check [the source code](https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/bind9/bind9-45.1/bind9/lib/dns/rdata.c), the function is `txt_totext()`

Answer (score 1):

You can format the data for use with `recode`:

```
$ echo '"\228\184\173\230\150\135"' | tr -c '0-9' '\n' | recode -f d1..data; echo
中文
$
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution! However `recode` is not installed by default in many distros, I need a simple solution without many hoops requires end-user to install this using that. Thanks!

Comment: Python is standard. Why don't you inline your code?

Comment: Yup, if no simpler solution is found I'll try inline perl or python.